# How can I make a method takes the value(s) from another method from within the same class in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

I have the following Class and the corresponding method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def bar(self):
        bar_out = self.x + 5
        return bar_out
    def qux(self):
        qux_out = bar_out + 3
        return qux_out

def main():
    """docstring for main"""
    f = Foo(5)

    main_bar_out = f.bar()
    print main_bar_out

    #main_qux_out = f.qux()
    #print main_qux_out



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I want to do here is to make the method `a=qux` takes the value from `bar`, process it and return a value. So that the final output of `main_qux_out` is 13.  How can I do this correctly?

Note that here I want `qux()` to take the value automatically from `bar()`, without passing any parameter.

**Update**

Thanks for @thefourtheye, for the response. I have further questions.

Let say if I want to have `bar()` to return two or more values (this can be string, string, list or dict), how can I call it from `qux()`. I tried this but failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def bar(self):
        self.bar1_out = self.x + 5
        self.bar2_out = self.x + 1
        return (self.bar1_out,self.bar2_out)
    def qux(self):
        self.qux_out1 = self.bar1_out() + 3
        self.qux_out2 = self.bar2_out() + 6
        return ( self.qux_out1, self.qux_out2)

def main():
    """docstring for main"""
    f = Foo(5)

    mbr_out1, mbr_out2 = f.bar()
    print mbr_out1, "\t", mbr_out2

    mqx_out1, mqx_out2 = f.qux()
    print mqx_out1, "\t", mqx_out2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This should print:

```
10  6
13  12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access a local variable defined in one function, from another function. But you can invoke the `bar` function and use the return value like this

```
def qux(self):
    return self.bar() + 3
```

If you want to decide which value to use (`bar` or the value passed as parameter) dynamically, then you can do something like this

```
def qux(self, myvalue = None):
    if myvalue is not None:
        return myvalue + 3
    else:
        return self.bar() + 3
```

If you don't pass any value to `qux`, `myvalue` will be default take `None` as its value. Inside the function, we check if it is not `None`, then we use the value as it it, otherwise we call `self.bar()` and use that value.

If you are planning to return two values from `bar`, then you can unpack them like this

```
def qux(self, myvalue = None):
    first, second = myvalue or self.bar()
    return first + 3, second + 6
```

Here `myvalue or self.bar()` makes sure that we take `self.bar()` if `myvalue` is `None`.

**Note:** If you are planning to do this way, then you need pass two values for `myvalue` as well, like this

```
self.qux((1, 2))
```

Comment: @thefoureyes: Thanks a million. How can I make `qux()` optionally takes `self.bar()` or user defined parameter. So, when I call `qux()` it takes, self.bar() and when I call `qux(myvalue)` it takes `myvalue` instead?

Comment: @thefortheyes: Thanks again. One last question. Let say I have two values from bar() to pass, how can I call it from qux()? See update.

Comment: @thefortheye: Thanks a million again. For giving me a great OOP lesson!

Answer (score 1):

methods inside of a class can only access variables of that class or variables defined inside the method. What you ought to do is either make bar a variable of the class (instead of being part of the method)

```
def bar(self):
    self.bar_out = self.x + 5
    return self.bar_out
```

or call bar() and use the output in the calculation

```
def qux(self):    
    qux_out = self.bar() + 3
```

Comment: Thanks. With your first example, how can i call `self.bar_out` from `qux()`